# Quarkus Helm problem mapping int env variables

Tags: java, properties, kubernetes-helm, quarkus, testcontainers

I use these properties:

```
icap.is-enabled=${ICAP_ENABLED:'false'}
icap.hostname=${ICAP_HOSTNAME:localhost}
icap.port=${ICAP_PORT:'1344'}
icap.request-source=${ICAP_SOURCE:file}
icap.servicename=${ICAP_SERVICENAME:srv_clamav}
icap.username=${ICAP_USERNAME:user}
```

I use these extensions in my build.gradle:

```
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-kubernetes'
    implementation 'io.quarkiverse.helm:quarkus-helm:0.2.8'
```

And the result are these entries in my values.yaml file in my helm build folder:

```
  envs:
    ICAP_SOURCE: file
    ICAP_HOSTNAME: localhost
    ICAP_SERVICENAME: srv_clamav
    ICAP_USERNAME: user
    ICAP_PORT: '''1344'''
    ICAP_ENABLED: '''false'''
```

I use the variables like this in my application:

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "icap")
public interface IcapConfig {

    boolean isEnabled();

    String hostname();

    int port();

    String servicename();

    String username();

    String requestSource();
}
```

The env variable "ICAP_PORT" is the problem. Either Helm or the application will complain about the type of the variable.

My workaround at the moment is this properties configuration:

```
icap.port=1344
quarkus.kubernetes.env-vars.icap-port.value='1344'
```

However, I wonder what the correct way of configuring an int properties value would be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, mapping system properties to env properties only work for String values.

To map other types, you would need to use the Quarkus Helm Values configuration which supports more complex types like [integers](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-helm/dev/index.html#quarkus-helm_quarkus.helm.values.-values-.value-as-int), [booleans](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-helm/dev/index.html#quarkus-helm_quarkus.helm.values.-values-.value-as-bool), [maps](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-helm/dev/index.html#quarkus-helm_quarkus.helm.values.-values-.value-as-map-value-as-map) and [lists](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-helm/dev/index.html#quarkus-helm_quarkus.helm.values.-values-.value-as-list).

For example, after using the system property like:

```
icap.port=${ICAP_PORT}
```

Then you can configure the Quarkus Helm Values extension to use the integer as follows:

```
quarkus.helm.values."envs.ICAP_PORT".value-as-int=1111
```

Comment: Thanks Jose. Much love for quarkus-helm :)

Comment: I also found this example in the latest quarkus helm documentation on how to solve this: https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-helm/dev/example-config.html